# How to display only the negative contour labels?

Tags: qgis

How can I hide the positive contour labels covering the green area and only display the negative contour labels over the ocean areas? I am using QGIS 2.18.2. The contour file is a separate layer and when I enable labels I cannot hide the positive contours. Refer to the image below.

[image: Contours showing up on land area]

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121585/qgis-choose-contour-line-labels/121591#121591

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `if` statement to only show values which are negative, something like the following:

```
if("fieldName" < 0, "fieldName", '')
```

[image: Example]

---

Example:

- Before using `if` statement (blue = positive contours; red = negative contours):

  [image: Before statement]
- After using `if` statement:

  [image: After statement]