# Creating index contours using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression

I'm testing out QGIS for the first time, and I'm trying to find a way to highlight index contours.

I'd like to be able to do so via the layer Symbology, or if necessary by separating out the index contours I want into a separate layer.

I've tried building a query to select every 10th contour using the `generate_series` expression, but I'm not well versed in crafting these and thus far I haven't been successful.

Comment: You should edit the question, to add details of what you tried

Comment: Have a look at [Choosing only one contour line to label in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/121585/48394)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to create a filter to select index contours using the expression `("Z" % 10) = 0` where "Z" refers to the elevation attribute, and "10" is the interval I wanted for my index contours.

[image: Index Contour Rule]